# columns not resizing properly for mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I resize the window for mobile view (below 550px width), I want the columns to stretch width according to the window size. Instead, the blue column is slightly smaller than the viewport width and yellow, red and green columns shrink way too much.

this is the result i'm getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CXWf.jpg

this is the result i want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/75h13.jpg

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
p{
    font-size: 10px;
}
.inBody{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;

}
.forAll{
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;

}
.verticalOption{
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.verticalOption a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 5px;
}
.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items:  center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.opened{
    display: none;
}
.close{
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 550px){
    .inBody{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;

    }
    .verticalOption {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    .forAll{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;

    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="no-gutters">
    <div class="fluid-container inBody">
        <div class="container col-xl-9 col-sm-9 col-9 col1 forAll bg-primary">
            <h2 class="verticalOption opened" id="menuHome"><a href="#" id="home">Sample</a></h2>
            <div class="container content allContent" id="homeContent">
                <h1>HOME</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container col-xl-1 col-sm-1 col-1 col2 forAll bg-warning">
            <h2 class="verticalOption" id="menuAbout"><a href="#" id="about">Sample</a></h2>
            <div class="container content close allContent" id="aboutContent">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container col-xl-1 col-sm-1 col-1 col3 forAll bg-danger">
            <h2 class="verticalOption" id="menuContact"><a href="#" id="contact">Contact Me</a></h2>
            <div class="container content allContent close" id="contactContent">
                <h1>Sample</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container col-xl-1 col-sm1 col-1 col4 forAll bg-success">
            <h2 class="verticalOption" id="menuPortfolio"><a href="#" id="portfolio">Sample</a></h2>
            <div class="container content allContent close" id="portfolioContent">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `col-1` class, according to Bootstrap 4+ col-* is used to set the width in small devices [source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
p{
    font-size: 10px;
}
.inBody{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;

}
.forAll{
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;

}
.verticalOption{
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.verticalOption a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 5px;
}
.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items:  center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.opened{
    display: none;
}
.close{
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 550px){
    .inBody{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;

    }
    .verticalOption {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    .forAll{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;

    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="no-gutters">
    <div class="fluid-container inBody">
        <div class="container col-xl-9 col-sm-9 col-9 col1 forAll bg-primary">
            <h2 class="verticalOption opened" id="menuHome"><a href="#" id="home">Sample</a></h2>
            <div class="container content allContent" id="homeContent">
                <h1>HOME</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container col-xl-1 col-sm-1  col2 forAll bg-warning">
            <h2 class="verticalOption" id="menuAbout"><a href="#" id="about">Sample</a></h2>
            <div class="container content close allContent" id="aboutContent">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container col-xl-1 col-sm-1  col3 forAll bg-danger">
            <h2 class="verticalOption" id="menuContact"><a href="#" id="contact">Contact Me</a></h2>
            <div class="container content allContent close" id="contactContent">
                <h1>Sample</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container col-xl-1 col-sm1  col4 forAll bg-success">
            <h2 class="verticalOption" id="menuPortfolio"><a href="#" id="portfolio">Sample</a></h2>
            <div class="container content allContent close" id="portfolioContent">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquid animi asperiores
                    consequuntur debitis delectus dignissimos dolorum esse est facilis fuga ipsum maxime minus molestiae
                    mollitia neque odio perferendis, placeat quasi quia quo repellendus sunt suscipit ullam veniam
                    voluptatem voluptatum. Atque blanditiis deserunt, dignissimos dolorum eos expedita id illo iusto maiores
                    pariatur perferendis quam quo repudiandae temporibus totam. A ab accusamus accusantium atque
                    consequuntur deserunt dignissimos dolor eos ex excepturi expedita impedit inventore, laborum magni
                    maiores minus nam, nisi numquam odio officia officiis optio perferendis qui quidem quis rem, sunt
                    temporibus tenetur vitae voluptate? Nesciunt nulla possimus sapiente voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be caused by the `col-1` which is means the default size of the columns is 1/12. You can solve the size by changing `col-1` to `col` for 12/12 (100%) width as default (smallest breakpoint) to achieve the desired width. You might have to set an height though.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jesprj/pen/xeGgpG

Answer (score 1):

Try to add`col-xs-12` bootstrap class to each container and remove `col-1`

```
<div class="container col-xl-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12 col2 forAll bg-warning">
```

Herre the js-fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bodybow/odtL97n1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just change width:100% to max-width:100% for .forAll class in media query

```
@media (max-width: 550px) {
    .inBody {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    .verticalOption {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    .forAll {
        height: 100vh;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```